# Syntax error, unexpected '', expecting 'function'

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax

I'm using Ecplise and I'm getting strange syntax errors, it says there are four errors each located on the line before each function declaration (except for the constructor). I really don't know where it can come from, I checked every line and I see no "{}" or ";" problems...

```
<?php
require_once('SqliteConnection.php');
class TrajetDAO {
private static $dao;

private function __construct() {
}​
public final static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$dao)) {
        self::$dao= new TrajetDAO();
    }
    return self::$dao;
}
​
public final function findAll() {
    $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
    $query = "select * from Trajet order by num";
    $stmt = $dbc->query($query);
    $results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, ’Trajet’);
    return $results;
}
​
public final function insert(DataObject $st){
    if($st instanceof Trajet){
        $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
        // prepare the SQL statement
        $query = "insert into Trajet(num, description, dateCrea) values (:n,:de,:da)";
        $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);

        // bind the paramaters
        $stmt->bindValue(":n",$st->getNum(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":de",$st->getDescription(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":da",$st->getdateCrea(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute($data);
    }
}

public function delete(DataObject $obj) {
    $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
    $query = $dbConnection->prepare('DELETE FROM Trajet WHERE num='.$Trajet->getNum().';');
    $query->execute();
}
​
public function update(DataObject $obj) {
    $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
    $query=$dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE Trajet SET num='.$Trajet->getNum().',description='.$Trajet->getDescription().',dateCrea='.$teacher->getDateCrea(). 'WHERE num='.$Trajet->getNum().';');
    $query->execute();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell in which line the errors occur?

Comment: remove `require_once('SqliteConnection.php');` and check again

Comment: I'd say remove your empty `__construct()` and try again.

Comment: The code works or only eclipse complain?

Comment: `unexpected ''`? Maybe an invisible/unprintable char in there that counts as "code" and not "whitespace"

Comment: I just tried running this and `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€‹' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)` on line 7

Comment: @MarcB Ahh, Is that even possible? `>_<`

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari same here https://eval.in/443166

Comment: `public static final`

Comment: @AlanMachado Ahh, Let's just wait for someone to break the ice `;-)`

Comment: Just made a test: 1) erase `__construct()` declaration completely (brackets and all), save it and run 2) re-write it, save and run again. The error's gone. Probably some hidden character as @MarcB said --> https://eval.in/443172 (still throws error, but different context)

Comment: @AlanMachado Ahh, So this is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think, like the commenters, that this was an issue with an invisible character. By removing and replacing the characters near the syntax errors I managed to get rid of all of them in PHPStorm at least.

If you wrote this code yourself you might want to look into your setup to find the root cause.

```
<?php
require_once('SqliteConnection.php');
class TrajetDAO {
    private static $dao;

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public final static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$dao)) {
            self::$dao = new TrajetDAO();
        }

        return self::$dao;
    }

    public final function findAll()
    {
        $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
        $query = "select * from Trajet order by num";
        $stmt = $dbc->query($query);
        $results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, `Trajet`);

        return $results;
    }

    public final function insert(DataObject $st){
        if($st instanceof Trajet){
            $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
            // prepare the SQL statement
            $query = "insert into Trajet(num, description, dateCrea) values (:n,:de,:da)";
            $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);

            // bind the paramaters
            $stmt->bindValue(":n",$st->getNum(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":de",$st->getDescription(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":da",$st->getdateCrea(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            // execute the prepared statement
            $stmt->execute($data);
        }
    }

    public function delete(DataObject $obj) {
        $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
        $query = $dbConnection->prepare('DELETE FROM Trajet WHERE num='.$Trajet->getNum().';');
        $query->execute();
    }

    public function update(DataObject $obj) {
        $dbc = SqliteConnection::getInstance()->getConnection();
        $query=$dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE Trajet SET num='.$Trajet->getNum().',description='.$Trajet->getDescription().',dateCrea='.$teacher->getDateCrea(). 'WHERE num='.$Trajet->getNum().';');
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: It was indeed due to invisible characters, I sent my file to someone and he could see them.